# $host.setshouldexit() Does Not Exit

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a situation where a compiled app calls cmd.exe which runs a batch file that calls

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command “& {.\script.ps1}
```

`script.ps1` has the line `$host.setshouldexit($exitcode)`.

But for some reason the powershell.exe process executing the PS1 doesn’t exit. Even if I run

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command “& {.\script.ps1;Exit $lastexitcode}
```

it never gets past the PS1 to the Exit command. Adding `Exit` to the end of the PS1 doesn't work either. The real annoyance is that all of this works just fine if I manually fire up CMD, open another CMD to replicate the compiled app doing it, and execute the batch file that calls powershell.exe.

Comment: Is your app calling `cmd.exe /c` or `cmd.exe /k`?  Also you could just call `exit $exitcode`.

Comment: You are missing trailling quotes in your samples. Is that just a copy paste error? Also I see smart quotes. Use regular quotes in your real codes. Those can sometimes cause issues `“` > `"`

Comment: @Matt The end quotes are missing.

Comment: @BaconBits looked at the app source code today. It is C++ and calling the batch file with `cmd.exe /c`. I could call `exit $exitcode` but it isn't always accurate. `$host.setshouldexit($exitcode)` gives us consistent results and works everywhere else. It just isn't working when called using `cmd /c` by the app.

Comment: To give an example of why to use SetShouldExit, I have a ps1 script that simply calls `$host.SetShouldExit(1234)`. Watch what happens when I use `Exit $LASTEXITCODE`.  
  -----  
`cmd /c test.cmd`  
`powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {".\Test.ps1";Exit $LASTEXITCODE}"`  
`echo errorlevel: 0`  
  -----  
`cmd /c test.cmd`  
`powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {".\Test.ps1"}"`  
`echo errorlevel: 1234`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the is an error with the post you made. The missing closing 'Double Quote', but I am sure that was a copy paste thing.

Yet, try changing your posted commands to this:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process powershell .\script.ps1}"

powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command “& {Start-Process .\script.ps1;Exit $lastexitcode}"
```

Even without this...

```
$host.setshouldexit()
```

...they should auto close.

Comment: I know it should close without '$host.setshouldexit()' but we use it to consistently pass error codes back to cmd.exe. What is the benefit of calling `Start-Process` instead of the .PS1 directly?

Answer (score 0):

Check your working directory

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command “& {pwd;.\script.ps1}"
```

seems like the working directory is wrong and is important as you are using relative path.

else give the absolute path to the script.

Comment: The script runs fine. It just doesn't close.

Comment: what is content in sciprt.ps1 ?

Comment: For the purposes of the example, it just has $host.SetShouldExit(1234).

Comment: what is the PowerShell version here ?